# What have I done to Preview in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, preview

I used to open the annotations toolbar and I could select, for example, the arrow tool. Then I would click from A to B and draw the arrow.

Now when I click the arrow tool it plops an arrow on the screenshot and I have to manually drag both ends.

This seems like extra work compared to the old way, what am I likely to have done to have caused this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I totally agree. Now it's so annoying to work with it that I will probably move to Skitch. I was so happy with the previous arrow functionality :(

Comment: What's worse it is the same for all the tools in that bar. Not one works "as expected". Shame really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this. Clicking the Arrow tool does indeed simply add an arrow instead of having you drag it out first.

I rarely if ever use the Annotate toolbar, so I am certain I have not made any changes that would have caused this. More likely, the upgrade to Yosemite changed how this tool works.

Comment: Point of comment, this seems to be the case for all annotations, not just arrows, I just chose that as an example.

Comment: Very bad news. This just went a lot worse. It was very handful and now I need to use Skitch to have something similar